# how can you make a toplevel window on android through qt or by calling JNI through qt?

Tags: android, c++, qt, java-native-interface

I wanted to make an android app or activity ( sry i don't know much about android ) using qt that is topLevel
this thing works for me in windows using the Qt::Popup flag but on android i don't know how i can make my little window always on top of others apps while letting me use what's in the background normally like how apps like messenger can display a little bubble when you got a knew message and let's you touche whatever is not under the bubble normally.
it seems that i can call JNI through qt, i don't know if that helps finding a solution ..

Comment: Android Toast https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts

Comment: i need to interact with the window too ..